# Position Gtk# Dialog in the center of a Gtk window

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk, gtk#

Im trying to position a GTK# dialog in the center of a window,also i would like to make the parent window non editable when this dialog appears.
I tried setting the `parent` property and of the dialog and set it's position to `center on parent`.(The parent windows position is always centered,the parent appers centered but a portion of it is below the taskbar)

What im i doing wrong?

***UPDATE:***

I tried setting the transcientfor property.

```
        mywin d = new mywin();
        d.Parent = this;
        d.WindowPosition = WindowPosition.CenterOnParent; 
        d.TransientFor = this; 
        d.WidthRequest = 360;
        d.HeightRequest =260;
        d.Resizable = false; 
        d.Show ();
```

Also i get this error in Application Output when i do this

```
(myapp:5844): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget

(myapp:5844): Gdk-CRITICAL **: inner_clipboard_window_procedure: assertion 'success' failed
```

UPDATE:
Calling the dialog from parent

```
protected void OnButton7Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var mydiag = new mydiag( this );

            if ( ( (Gtk.ResponseType) mydiag.Run() ) == Gtk.ResponseType.Ok ) {
                // do whatever here...
            }
     }
```

Dialog code

```
using System;

namespace myproj
{
    public partial class mydiag : Gtk.Dialog
    {
        public mydiag (Gtk.Window parent)
        {
            this.Build ();
            this.Title = parent.Title + " more info";
            this.Icon = parent.Icon;
            this.Parent = parent;
            this.TransientFor = parent;
            this.SetPosition( Gtk.WindowPosition.CenterOnParent );
            this.ShowAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the dialog as `transient_for` the parent? (If you passed the parent as the `parent` parameter to one of the standard GtkDialog constructors, then yes.)

Comment: @andlabs I tried it too.Please see the update.

Comment: The `Parent` property of `GtkWidget` is completely different; it has to do with `GtkContainer`. Get rid of that line. What OS and window manager are you using?

Comment: @andlabs Im using windows now.But the app is intended for Mac,does this have any effect on how windows are managed.I don't know what window manager im using.Im simply using Xamarin Studio(Mono+Gtk#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is being reported here:

```
(myapp:5844): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on a toplevel widget
```

Your **mywin** class is not a **Gtk.Dialog**, but probably a **Gtk.Window**. You should create your main window this way:

```
namespace Whatever {
    public class MainWindow: Gtk.Window {
        public MainWindow()
            : base( Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel )
        {
            this.Title = "Gtk# App";
            this.Build();
        }

        private void Build() {
            // create your widgets
        }

        // more things...
}
```

Suppose now that you need to open a dialog for some function in your app.

```
namespace Whatever {
    public class MainWindow: Gtk.Window {
        // ...more things
        private void OnWhatever() {
            var dlg = new DlgMoreInfo( this );

            if ( ( (Gtk.ResponseType) dlg.Run() ) == Gtk.ResponseType.Ok ) {
                // do whatever here...
            }

            dlg.Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to create your dialog **DlgMoreInfo** centered, etc.

```
namespace Whatever {
    public class DlgMoreInfo : Gtk.Dialog {
        public DlgMoreInfo(Gtk.Window parent) {
            this.Build();

            this.Title = parent.Title + " more info";
            this.Icon = parent.Icon;
            this.TransientFor = parent;
            this.SetPosition( Gtk.WindowPosition.CenterOnParent );
            this.ShowAll();
        }

        private void Build() {
            // Create widgets here...
            // Buttons
            this.AddButton( Gtk.Stock.Cancel, Gtk.ResponseType.Cancel );
            this.AddButton( Gtk.Stock.Ok, Gtk.ResponseType.Ok );
            this.DefaultResponse = Gtk.ResponseType.Ok;
        }
    }
}
```

You can only create dialogs which are childs of a top level window; never a window can be a child of another one.

Note that this code does not use the designer of **Xamarin Studio**. If you use the designer, then call *HideAll()* just before *ShowAll()*, if you need to use the widgets, or move the call to *Build()* after the call to *SetPosition()*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. its a window indeed.actually i had a dialog earlier .. i replaced it so got confused.Now i have changed the class to dialog > " public partial class mywin: Gtk.Dialog" <  .I cannot change the UI.Is there any way i can keep the existing UI and show this as a dialog.

Comment: I guess you're using Xamarin Studio. Create a new dialog in the normal way, and copy/paste the components. Anyway, my advice is to get rid of the designer.

Comment: Yeah im using Xamarin Studio.How can i copy paste the components ? Will normal copying work? When i changed the class to dialog there are no widgets in the dialog just empty(when executed).Also the designer puts some buttons as default in a new dialog,i cannot get rid of those .. so i switched to window.Is there a way by which i can make a window act like a dialog.I only want it centered.

Comment: Normal copying will do. Sorry, I don't know of a way to center a window on its parent, since there is not such concept for windows. I can only recommend you again to get rid of the designer. Coding the layout by hand, there won't be buttons in a dialog if you don't add them. Check this out: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/

Comment: I tried adding the code you have provided in the newly created dialog.The main window was non editable when the dialog showed.But the dialog is  not centered on the parent.

Comment: I'm sorry it did not work for you. Normally, dialogs are modal, though you can set the *Modal* property to false to select otherwise. Check that you call *ShowAll()* after setting the window position, transient and parent.

Comment: ¿public partial class? You're obviously still using the designer. The problem is that, inside *Build()*, the designer has already called *ShowAll()*, so all the modifications to the position do not take effect. Call *HideAll()* just before *ShowAll()* in your code. Or move *Build()* to the line after the call to *SetPosition()*.